# What is the correct way to use the critical-section 1.1.0 crate on AVR Rust?

Tags: rust, avr

Create a new rust project using `cargo generate --git https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git`

Add `critical-section="1.1.0"` to the dependencies in `Cargo.toml` .  Add this to `src/main.rs`

```
critical_section::with(|cs| {
    let x = 42;
});
```

When I compile the crate I get errors:

```
error: linking with `avr-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "avr-gcc" "-mmcu=atmega328p" "-Wl,--as-needed" "/tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/csblam-8084998631809f52.critical_section-84877c508187b600.critical_section.2f379ae8-cgu.0.rcgu.o.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps" "-L" "/tmp/csblam/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/thoth/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-07-10-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,--end-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-37b50c9b1b42d179.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/thoth/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2022-07-10-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/avr-atmega328p/lib" "-o" "/tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/csblam-8084998631809f52.elf" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie"
  = note: /usr/libexec/gcc/avr/ld: /tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/csblam-8084998631809f52.critical_section-84877c508187b600.critical_section.2f379ae8-cgu.0.rcgu.o.rcgu.o: in function `_ZN16critical_section7acquire17h65b5f9939644d800E':
          /home/thoth/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/critical-section-1.1.0/src/lib.rs:180: undefined reference to `_critical_section_1_0_acquire'
          /usr/libexec/gcc/avr/ld: /tmp/csblam/target/avr-atmega328p/debug/deps/csblam-8084998631809f52.critical_section-84877c508187b600.critical_section.2f379ae8-cgu.0.rcgu.o.rcgu.o: in function `_ZN16critical_section7release17h18a607ec6f135f58E':
          /home/thoth/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/critical-section-1.1.0/src/lib.rs:197: undefined reference to `_critical_section_1_0_release'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)
```

What is the correct technique for using the critical-section crate on AVR Rust?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just found the solution. Better late than never, I guess.

The problem is that the `critical-sections` crate only provides the interface for embedded libraries to use critical sections but doesn't actually provide an implementation defining the `acquire` and `release` symbols, hence resulting in that linker error. This is intentional to allow end-users to plug in a suitable implementation for their platform. The docs actually address this point quite clearly: https://docs.rs/critical-section/1.1.1/critical_section/#undefined-reference-errors

What was not so obvious to me is where to find the suitable implementation crate. None of the *direct* dependencies of the `avr-hal-template` has a corresponding feature flag, but I finally figured out that the transitive dependency `avr-device` (which is the Peripheral Access Crate (PAC) which the `avr-hal` Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) is built upon) does! So adding

```ini
avr-device = { version = "0.5.1", features = ["critical-section-impl"] }
```

to my `Cargo.toml` file did the trick.